# Copy blob from Azure storage account to a Network Path

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy blob across storage accounts. To be specific I am trying to copy a blob of 1 GB from West Europe region to West US region. The West Europe region has Azure blob but destination i.e. West US region is a **network path**(`\\something\something`).

The way I am doing it now is a simple download blob as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#download-blobs). The speeds are really very low. The source code to copy/download blob is run from a region different from source and destination region.

What should be the efficient way of copying blob from Azure storage to a Network Path?

PS: I have worked with AzCopy and Data Movement Library for copying blob across storage accounts. The speed is quite fast when I copy from one Azure Storage account to other. But the speeds are terrible when I copy/download from Azure Storage account to network path.

Comment: Is this network path mapped to a File Share?

Comment: @GauravMantri: No, its not. Does mapping the destination network path with File Share improve the performance? Or are there any different solutions if mapping is done?

Comment: @GauravMantri: When it comes to Azure, I always wait a bit more hoping Gaurav has an answer. Any inputs other than mentioned in answers?

Comment: Shridhar, I am flattered :). Can you please tell me how are you mapping the network path? AFAIK, blob storage can't be mapped as network drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a new Storage Account in West US and copying the blob from West Europe Account to it using AZCopy. After that, you could download the blob to your Network Path from the new storage Account.

I just tested it on my side. Copying a 1.1G size blob storage from one Storage Account in  West Europe to another Storage Account in West US spent about 160 seconds(average transfer speed 7MB/S).  Following is the sample copy command.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://account1.blob.core.windows.net/container1 /Dest:https://account2.blob.core.windows.net/container2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:yourblobname.ext
```

Comment: That's a good one and tried it yesterday .. could do it in total of 9 minutes! If no other answer is posted, I'll accept this. As of now I don't see any problem with this approach, but can there be any other possible way?

Comment: I am doing it in c# and I am able to do blob of 5 GB copy across Azure storage accounts from West Europe to West US just within 5 seconds! Please comment why the speed is good as well just for my curiosity.

Comment: I guess that Azure Storage Service will compute the hash code of the file which you want copy. If there is a same file which has the same hash code in another data center. It will not need to transfer the file between two data centers.

Comment: I am copying into an empty storage account. The approach about hash which you are guessing has a performance hit if there are many files and it has to compute hash for all.

Comment: `I am doing it in c# and I am able to do blob of 5 GB copy across Azure storage accounts from West Europe to West US just within 5 seconds! Please comment why the speed is good as well just for my curiosity.` - Azure Blob Copy operation is async operation. 5 seconds is the time Azure Storage took to put the blobs to be copied in a queue. It doesn't mean that the blobs are copied at the destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

AzCopy is a command-line utility designed for copying data to and from Microsoft Azure Blob, File, and Table storage using simple commands with **optimal performance**. You can copy data from one object to another within your storage account, or between storage accounts.

[image: AzCopy to network path]

Comment: Can you point me to a specific command other than Download? Because I have explored AzCopy as well as Data Movement Library. Also my constraint is to copy/download to a network path.

Comment: I use the command: `AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /Dest:**C:\myfolder** /SourceKey:key /S`, replacing **C:\myfolder** with the mapped network path.

Comment: That is same as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#download-blobs.